# Is there a way for a desktop application to connect to a remote sever with socket.io

Tags: javascript, sockets, heroku, socket.io, electron

I am trying to connect to a remote server that I deployed on Heroku from a desktop application.

```
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('listening to', port);
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('send', function(data) {
    socket.emit('sever send msg', data);
  }
});
```

That is my server code and I have that server deployed to Heroku, is there a way for me to connect to this server with sockets from a desktop application? I am using Electron to try to make a desktop application and am trying to get socket.io to work with a remote server. Below is the relevant code from my desktop application.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io('THE HEROKU APP URL');
      $('form').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
      });
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
      });
    </script>
    <div id="root"></div>
</html>
```

At the moment I keep getting a 503 failed to connect service unavailable

Comment: are you listening and connecting on the same port?

Comment: I'm not familiar with heroku, but I see the code in the top snippet specifies a PORT, defaulting to 3000, but the code in the second snippet makes no mention of a PORT - I'm just wondering if you are using the same PORT on each side of the connection ... while the PORT is technically a part of the URL, I asked about the PORT only, assuming you would at least use the right HOST and PATH in the URL

Comment: without revealing the `'THE HEROKU APP URL'` - does it include a PORT

Comment: The 'THE HEROKU APP URL' does not the include the port at the moment but i am not sure which port to add to the url to connect correctly

Comment: I'd recommend the same PORT your server side is listening on

Comment: `listen to a port on the client side` generally makes no sense - client initiates a connection, server listens

Comment: Sorry I got a bit confused should have been more clear, I had it server listen to the whatever the port was set as and I edited the code to show that and I am trying to connect to that sever with the heroku app URL. Is the problem that I have to include the port in io.() on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to include the port on your desktop app. One thing you can do is to chech the request error cause - i have faced similar problems when deploying apps using socket.io on heroku. A cause may be that you are missing something like:

```
 io.origins("*:*") 
// or 
 io.set("origins", "*:*");
```

in your app.js or whatever you called your node file on heroku.
 I do not recommend using "*:*" for production.

You can have a look at https://github.com/joan41868/ts-mysafemessage-api or https://github.com/joan41868/mysafemessage for examples, i have used sockets on both of them, and the first one ( deployed at: https://mysafemessage.herokuapp.com ) is currently up and working.